# if, else if, is there a better way for me to run this code?

Tags: for-loop, if-statement

So i am new to python,

I am trying to run this code, but considering I am using a lot of copy and paste, my instincts suggest there's an easier more simple way to write this code. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks;

```
row = 1 
#generating row number
#[int(x) for x in str(cardnum)]
if cardnum in range(1,22):
    row = row
elif cardnum in range(22,32):
    row += 1
elif cardnum in range(32,52):
    row += 2
elif cardnum in range(52,72):
    row += 3
elif cardnum in range(72,92):
    row += 4
elif cardnum in range(92,112):
    row += 5
elif cardnum in range(112,132):
    row += 6
elif cardnum in range(132,152):
    row += 7    
elif cardnum in range(152,172):
    row += 8
elif cardnum in range(162,182):
    row += 9
elif cardnum in range(192,212):
    row += 10
```

Comment: You have a discontinuity from 72 to 81. If there is no disco-unity and equally sized boxed, you can simply use division.

Comment: I know nothing about python but think math - how can you convert the ranges to the aditions?

Comment: @DeepankarArya thanks that was an error I have fixed

Comment: @ZoharPeled That's what I was thinking, maybe a for loop with an addition of 20?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
row = 1
if row in range(22, 212):
    row = 2 + (cardnum - 32) / 20
```